New door opens outward to the left want to reverse it
I bought a new door from a friend that works at a home improvement store. The door is too big for the frame of the doorway. The men that installed the door knocked the front steps off in order to have the door swing outward instead of inward. Now the opening handle is on the outside and it swings to the left. Is it possible to turn the entire door frame around (as it should be) and have the door swing outward to the right?

Exterior doors usually have a weather resistant side and an interior side, so changing swing usually isn’t just about flipping the door. Can you clarify (maybe with pictures) how your door is put together?

A left hand  pre-hung door, when switched around to the right side will be an  indoor swing.  There is a lot of info that is needed here.  Did you buy an exterior door?  Was it an out or in swing door? ( new codes in my area require all exterior doors to be out swing, for wind resistance.)  Why were steps knocked off?  Would it not be better to return the door and get one that fits properly ?

To determine the right or left swing of a door, open the door,  stand with your  back toward the hinges.  If the door is on your right side it's a right swing , if on your left it's a left swing.

If not possible to return the door(since installed), and it is a wooden door, it might be possible to shave/cut the top and/or bottom to size.  If so and local codes allow, then should be able to switch sides/turn around, frame and all.  Installers might have been made by local codes to have it open outwards.

@RMDman - most doors in my area swing in.   I believe you but never heard of making doors swing out because of wind?   Not sure I understand the logic to that code...   Really windy so my inward swinging door will have its lockset sheared off?    Also an outward swinging door IMO hits the elements more and if windy seems like it could be damaged.

@jennifer - do you have pictures?   Do you have a major issue with the door swinging inward?   Where did the previous door swing?

@DMoore,  New code in Fla. for hurricanes.   Exterior doors are beefed up and swing out, so wind and to a smaller degree water cannot force them in.  That does protect the home, at least until a giant tree limb crashes through the roof .  Insurance companies here get whatever they want.

@RMDman - I guess I understand in hurricane zones.  I guess it is the equivalent to boarding windows.   I still don't like my doors going out for a variety of reasons but if people are filing claims because their wood door popped I guess I see the logic.   It seems more logical to have a hurricane rated door (metal/fiberglass) with a certain amount of locksets (and depth).
